# how to use php to select value from a table use some keys

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to write a function which takes 2 parameters: one is a table name and another one is a associative array of keys. Now I have a function:

// returns an assoc array with all info in $table for given $keyValues 
`function getAllFrom($table,$keyValues){
    $qry="SELECT * FROM ". $table;
    $i=sizeof($keyValues);
    foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) {
         if($i==1) $qry.=" WHERE  ".$key."=".$keyValues[$key]." ";
         else $qry.=" AND ".$key."=".$keyValues[$key]." ";
         $i++;
            } 
    //echo " query is :   ".$qry;
    $result=mysql_query($qry) or die("Query $qry failed."); 
    if($results= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        return $results;
    else return false;
} // end getAllFrom`

But it is not work. Could anyone help me modify this and tell me what's foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) mean? I am confused.
Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you should explain what you are trying to achieve. And do yourself a favor and use brackets, even if your statement just contains one line of code. Its much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code can be solved, but I would rather tell you to not try to solve that specific code, since it is an old deprecated solution that you *want* to remove asap later on.

What you want to do is to use the PDO adapter http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Benefits from doing this is that you get protection from all the evils lurking in user input, and also you get a lot of nice abstractions solving exactly the problem you described.

This is a function I use to do this in my code, it might look a bit advanced but if you consult the manual you shouldn't have a problem solving it.

```
public function select( $table, array $conditions )
{
    $where = array();
    foreach ( $conditions as $col => $value )
    {            
        $input[":" . $col] = $value;
        $where[] = $col." = :" . $col;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT FROM " . $table
            . " WHERE ".implode("AND", $where);
    return (int) $this->prepare( $sql )
                    ->execute( $conditions )
                    ->getLastInsertId();
}
```

To understand Foreach loops I would read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
Another built in function I would recommend you looking into is the http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try:

```
function getAllFrom($table,$keyValues=null){
    $qry="SELECT * FROM ". $table . " WHERE 1 " ;
    if($keyValues){
        foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) {
            $qry.=" AND ".$key."=".$keyValues[$key]." ";
        }  
    }
    $result=mysql_query($qry) or die("Query $qry failed."); 
    if($results= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $results;
    }else{ 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have understood the concept of foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) correctly meaning if there is an associative array say

> $testArr =  array("key1"=>"val1","key2"=>"val2","key3"=>"val3")

then in each iteration of "foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val)"

$key would take values key1,key2,key3 and $val would take val2,val2 and val3 respectively.

Your query wont work because $i initially will not have value as 1 but it will have length of the associative array i.e. if $testArr is taken then it will have $i = 3. Your current query looks like this

> $qry = AND key1 = val1 AND key2 = val2 AND key3 =val3

, since if($i == 1) is never satisfied.

Also remember if values is a string then we need to have quotes around them so Try the below for the query you expect

```
 $i=1;
 foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val)
 {
     if($i==1) 
     {
        $qry.=" WHERE  ".$key."='".$keyValues[$key]."' ";   //the ' have to be included if value is a string and not number
        $i = 0;
     }
     else
     {
       $qry.=" AND ".$key."='".$keyValues[$key]."' ";
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getAllFrom($table,$keyValues){
        $qry="SELECT * FROM ". $table;
        $i=0;
        if(count($keyValues > 0)){
            foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) {
               if($i==0) $qry.=" WHERE  ".$key."=".$val." ";
               else $qry.=" AND ".$key."=".$val." ";
               $i++;
            } 
        }
        //echo " query is :   ".$qry;
        $result=mysql_query($qry) or die("Query $qry failed."); 
        if($results= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            return $results;
        else return false;
    } // end getAllFrom
```

if this helps dont froget to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, you actually need dynamic SQL Query based on your keyValue array parameters.

```
$sqlQuery ='SELECT * FROM '.$table;
$whereCondition='';
  foreach($keyValues as $key=>$val) {
      if($whereCondition =='')
          $whereCondition .= " WHERE  ".$key."=".$val." ";
      else
          $whereCondition .=" AND ".$key."=".$val." ";
 }

if($whereCondition !='')
      $sqlQuery .= $whereCondition;
```

Note:please be sure about your where condition values.

Answer (score 0):

**Function**
The function now returns multi dimensional array of all result rows. (your function returns only one result row even if have multiple results.)

```
function getAllFrom ($table,$keyValues)
{
   $returnArray = array();

   $qry = "SELECT * FROM ". $table;

   if (count($keyValues) > 0)
   {
       $qry .= " WHERE ";
       foreach ($keyValues as $key=>$val) 
       {
         $qry.= $key."=".$keyValues[$key]." AND ";
       }
       $qry = rtrim($qry, " AND ");
   }    //echo "query is : ".$qry."<br />";

   $result = mysql_query($qry);

   if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
   {
       while ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
       {
        $returnArray[] = $results;
       }
   }

   return $returnArray;
} // end getAllFrom
```

**Function Call**

```
$keyValues = array();
$keyValues['status'] = "'active'";
$keyValues['id'] = "'12'";

$resultArray = getAllFrom('products', $keyValues);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Notes**

$keyValues stores the query conditions. If this parameter is null ($keyValues = array()), function return all the rows